.mode column results in strange output with spatialite
I'm currently experimenting with SpatiaLite because I plan to eventually use it to programmatically generate a geodatabase from an API I have subscribed to. I already have sqlite3 available as a command in my terminal on Powershell. To be able to use SpatiaLite I opted for simply downloading the binaries from here and extracting them to a folder which I then added to the PATH environment variable. It seems to me that both spatialite and spatialite_tools work fine from my terminal now.
I did something very simple, first of all I created a brand new database as follows:
$ sqlite3 test.db

Then I created a basic table and inserted some values into it:
sqlite> CREATE TABLE points(id integer primary key autoincrement, name text not null, Xcoord real not null, Ycoord real not null);
sqlite> insert into points (name, Xcoord, Ycoord) values ("A", 1, 5);
sqlite> insert into points (name, Xcoord, Ycoord) values ("B", 3, 5);
sqlite> insert into points (name, Xcoord, Ycoord) values ("C", 0, -2);
sqlite> insert into points (name, Xcoord, Ycoord) values ("D", 3, -1);

With .headers on and .mode column, select * from points gives me properly formatted output:
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> .mode column
sqlite> select * from points;
id  name  Xcoord  Ycoord
--  ----  ------  ------
1   A     1.0     5.0
2   B     3.0     5.0
3   C     0.0     -2.0
4   D     3.0     -1.0

However, when I .exit out of sqlite3 and open the same database with spatialite, the output looks weird:
$ spatialite test.db
SpatiaLite version ..: 5.1.0    Supported Extensions:
        - 'VirtualShape'        [direct Shapefile access]
        - 'VirtualDbf'          [direct DBF access]
        - 'VirtualText'         [direct CSV/TXT access]
        - 'VirtualGeoJSON'              [direct GeoJSON access]
        - 'VirtualXL'           [direct XLS access]
        - 'VirtualNetwork'      [Dijkstra shortest path - obsolete]
        - 'RTree'               [Spatial Index - R*Tree]
        - 'MbrCache'            [Spatial Index - MBR cache]
        - 'VirtualFDO'          [FDO-OGR interoperability]
        - 'VirtualBBox'         [BoundingBox tables]
        - 'VirtualSpatialIndex' [R*Tree metahandler]
        - 'VirtualElementary'   [ElemGeoms metahandler]
        - 'VirtualRouting'      [Dijkstra shortest path - advanced]
        - 'VirtualKNN2' [K-Nearest Neighbors metahandler]
        - 'VirtualGPKG' [OGC GeoPackage interoperability]
        - 'VirtualXPath'        [XML Path Language - XPath]
        - 'SpatiaLite'          [Spatial SQL - OGC]
PROJ version ........: Rel. 9.2.1, June 1st, 2023
GEOS version ........: 3.12.0-CAPI-1.18.0
RTTOPO version ......: 1.1.0
TARGET CPU ..........: i686-w64-mingw32
SQLite version ......: 3.42.0
Enter ".help" for instructions
SQLite version 3.42.0 2023-05-16 12:36:15
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
spatialite> .mode column
spatialite> .headers on
spatialite> select * from points;
id          name        Xcoord      Ycoord
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           1           A           A           1.0         1.0         5.0
5.0
2           2           B           B           3.0         3.0         5.0
5.0
3           3           C           C           0.0         0.0         -2.0
-2.0
4           4           D           D           3.0         3.0         -1.0

The table looks fine without .mode column, so why does .mode column look different in SpatiaLite than it does on sqlite3?

Should I perhaps move this question to SO since it is more programming related?
